# switch case and enum in C++ error - expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

I cannot figure out the issue with this code:

```
class Class_name{
public:
    struct handler_struct
    {
        enum state_enum
        {
            Idle = 0,
            StartTX,
            Transmitting,
            TX_Error_SOF
        }state;
    }handler;
};

switch(Class_name::handler.state)
{
    case Class_name::handler.Idle:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The code works if I move the state enumeration of the struct the way it is defined outside. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: `handler_struct` is a type, `handler` is a member (of that type), you probably want `case Class_name::handler_struct::Idle:`.

Comment: `handler` is not static - which variable of type `Class_name` you want to access?